# Remain in bottom while animating footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `footer#footer` which contains company location. When I load contact page with hash `#location`javascript scrolls to the bottom of the page, and makes a callback to enlarge the footer, as it is the important element. How do I increase the size of the footer while the page remains at the bottom (so it seems like footer pushing up the content).

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash=="#location") {
    var scrollpos = $(document).height()-$(window).height()+"px"
    $("body,html").delay(200).animate({
        scrollTop: scrollpos
    }, "slow", function() { exfoot() });
}
function exfoot(){
    var $f = $("footer#footer");
    $f.animate({
        height: $f.height()*2
    }, "slow");
}
```

Comment: try to make a jsfiddle of it please

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should add it as an answer to your question, rather than editing the question to also include the answer.

Comment: @AndrewPolland , but is it ok That Asker gives answer himself ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Yes, if the asker has the answer then it's good to share it so others can benefit. Just including the answer with the question is messy and confusing. So it should be added as an answer to fit with the design of the system.

Comment: Oh, I thought :=> If asker knew answer ,why did he asked :)

Comment: @PratikJoshi because I didn't know and I kept trying till i found a solution so I thought It'd be a good idea to put it there.

Comment: @AndrewPolland Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: @PratikJoshi Because they can often work it out when no one else gives the right answer. I've done this a few times.

Comment: @wonderwhy Sorry, didn't realise about the time limit. Not convinced that editing question with an answer is a great idea, but I guess you're kinda stuck until the 8 hours are up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the function

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

so it looks

```
function exfoot(){
    var $f = $("footer#footer");
    $f.animate({
        height: $f.height()*2
    }, "slow");
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
}
```

Both the speed of the $f.animate and body,html.animate have to be the same, so they act simultaneously.